# Proving that $\Bbb Z$ has the same cardinality has $\Bbb N_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have seen some proofs concerning that $\Bbb Z$ is countable and in most of them, it's done by defining the following function:

\begin{equation*}
f(n) = \begin{cases}
      f(n) = \frac{n}{2} \text{ if $n$ even } \\[.15cm]
      f(n) = -\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \text{ if $n$ odd}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
But my only problem is the following: Consider the case where $\Bbb N_0$ is the domain of $f$. Thus we would have $f(0) = 0/2 = 0$ and $f(1) = -0/2 = 0$ which would prove that we aren't in a bijection. This is indeed a surjective function, is it being a surjective funciton enough to prove $\Bbb Z$ has the same size has $\Bbb N_0$? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be $-(n+1)/2$. Either that, or you don't include $0$.

Comment: Some people define $\Bbb N$ as the positive (rather than non-negative) integers.

Comment: Of $0\in\mathbb N,$ use $f(n+1).$

Comment: That's exactly what I mean @RobertShore

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you mean using $f(n) = -\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$ for $n$ odd and $f(n) = \frac{n+2}{2}$ for $n$ even?

Comment: Basically, there is a bijection between $\mathbb N_0$ and $\mathbb N_{>0},$ so a bijection between one of these and $X$ gives a bijection of the other and $X.$

Comment: Don’t reuse $f$ for a new function. $$g(n)=f(n+1)=\begin{cases}\frac{n+1}2&n+1\text{ even}\\-\frac{n}2&n+1\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ Of course, “$n+1$ even/odd” means “$n$ odd/even,” respectively.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So $g(n)=(-1)^n \lceil \frac n2 \rceil$?

Comment: Well, the function I’ve defined has $(-1)^{n+1},$ but there is no problem changing signs. You can definitely use your formula, if you’ve already defined the rationals and $\lceil\cdot\rceil.$ @RobertShore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ as given is a bijection $\mathbb N^{\geq1}\to\mathbb Z.$ If you want a bijection $\mathbb N^{\geq0}\to \mathbb Z$, you can just use the bijection $h:\mathbb N^{\geq0}\to\mathbb N^{\geq1},$ defined as $h(n)=n+1.$

The bijection $g=f\circ h:\mathbb N^{\geq0}\to \mathbb Z$ becomes:

$$g(n)=f(h(n))=f(n+1)=\begin{cases}\frac{n+1}2&n+1\text{ even}\\-\frac{n}2&n+1\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ Of course, “$n+1$ even/odd” means “$n$ odd/even,” respectively. So this becomes: $$g(n)=\begin{cases}\frac{n+1}2&n\text{ odd}\\-\frac{n}2&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$

---

This works in general, if you have a bijection $f:\mathbb N^{\geq1}\to X,$ there is a bijection $f\circ h:\mathbb N^{\geq0}\to X.$

Even more generally, a bijection $a:X\to Y$ and a bijection  $b:Y\to Z$ means we get a bijection $b\circ a:X\to Z.$

Answer (score 2):

Simply take $f(n) = -\frac{n+1}{2}$ for $n$ odd.

And yes, your original function is surjective but not injective. This suffices to prove the existence of a bijection. You have $f^{-1}(0) =\{0,1\}$ and all other fibers are singletons. Thus  you can remove one of $0,1$ from $\mathbb N_0$ and obtain a bijection from the smaller $\mathbb N_0 \setminus \{i\}$ to $\mathbb Z$. But if you remove a finite set from an infinite set, you do not change cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities: the first is to state that you found a surjection $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$, hence the $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb N)\ge\mathrm{card}(\mathbb Z)$.

Then the natural immersion $\mathbb N\hookrightarrow\mathbb Z$ gives an injection, that is $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb N)\ge\mathrm{card}(\mathbb Z)$.

Another solution is to define $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ as follows:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}n/2 & \text{if $n$ is even,}\\
-(n+1)/2 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
which is a bijection.